Web3 python websocket persistent connection
I am implementing a crypto payment system for my django web app. I have a smart contract that exposes some functions that let users purchase credits for my application by sending crypto to the smart contract. When a user calls one of these functions, an event containing the user id and the amount of credits purchased is logged by the contract.
Now I am trying to setup a persistent rpc websocket connection from my backend in order to catch all these events and update user credits accordingly.
These are my smart contract's events:
event EthPurchase(uint256 indexed userId, uint256 amountWei, uint256 creditsPurchased, uint256 when);
event UsdtPurchase(uint256 indexed userId, uint256 amountUsdt, uint256 creditsPurchased, uint256 when);
This is my Python code that should catch and handle events:
async def subscribe_to_purchase_events(self):
    backoff = 1

    while True:
        try:
            w3 = await AsyncWeb3(
                WebSocketProvider(
                    ETHEREUM_LOCALNET_WS_PROVIDER,
                    request_timeout=None,
                    subscription_response_queue_size=100000,
                    silence_listener_task_exceptions=False,
                ),
            )
            w3.middleware_onion.inject(
                web3.middleware.ExtraDataToPOAMiddleware,
                layer=0,
            )
            eth_purchase_event_topic = w3.keccak(
                text="EthPurchase(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)",
            )
            usdt_purchase_event_topic = w3.keccak(
                text="UsdtPurchase(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256)",
            )

            filter_params = {
                "address": VAULT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
                "topics": [
                    [eth_purchase_event_topic, usdt_purchase_event_topic],
                ],
            }

            subscription_id = await w3.eth.subscribe("logs", filter_params)

            backoff = 1

            async for payload in w3.socket.process_subscriptions():
                result = payload["result"]

                user_id = decode(["uint256"], result["topics"][1])[0]
                _, credits_purchased, _ = decode(
                    ["uint256", "uint256", "uint256"],
                    result["data"],
                )

                await self.handle_purchase_event(user_id, credits_purchased) #this is the helper function that adds credits to the user in response to event logs

        except Exception as e:  # noqa: BLE001
            print(f"Error in purchase events subscription: {e}")
            await asyncio.sleep(backoff)
            backoff = min(backoff * 1.5, 30)`

I am having trouble in keeping the subscription constantly catching and processing events.
When I run the subscribe_to_purchase_events function (using a dedicated service in a docker container), for some time everything works as expected: events logged by my smart contract are correctly catched and processed. After some time though, it stops working without raising any exception.
I think the execution is stuck in the async for payload in w3.socket.process_subscriptions():, because for some reason no events are being added to my subscription's queue. Again, this only happens after some time, at the beginning everything works fine.
I am currently testing this system with my contract deployed to a local Hardhat node that forks Ethereum mainnet.
Any idea what the reason could be and how can I fix this?
